# AngularJS: conditional binding is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to validate user's input onto the email address field inside a form, and I used to create a span in which the error message gets generated  in the case of typing an invalid value. This is the span HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='signupCtrl'>
          <span style="padding: 2px 0 2px 16px; color: red;" ng-if="check_mail()">Please type a valid email address</span>
          </div>
```

I used the `ng-if` tag for conditionally binding the error message

> Please type a valid email address

, and `check_mail()` function for checking the value from a `signupCtrl` controller.

The `check_mail` function works fine as expected. However the error message was never displayed though. So is there anything wrong on my HTML code? How is it possible to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if it's a basic question but does check_mail() function return boolean?

Comment: @erolkaya84 Yes, it does, I even checked with puting only `return false;` inside that function.

Comment: @user6039980 can we see your `check_mail` function?

Comment: could you provide a plunkr of your code?

Comment: @user6039980 There is nothing wrong with your set up but if the function is returning false then it wouldn't show up all. try changing it to `return true` or `!check_mail()`

Comment: can you provide your check_mail function?

Comment: @tanenbring @user1136560 @erolkaya84: I re-checked the JS function: and I found what the mistake was: The original function was for checking if the value is valid. So I just forgot to put `!` before the return value.

Comment: @kugyousha That's what I had to do. Thanks too much.

Comment: When you have an answer, activate the green ticket (which you've done). Don't add the word "solved" to question titles.

Comment: @Quentin: Ok, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does the function check_mail() returns true if the mail is invalid? if it doesnt then you may want to try

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='signupCtrl'>
      <span style="padding: 2px 0 2px 16px; color: red;" ng-if="!check_mail()">Please type a valid email address</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: That's what I had exactly to do. Thanks for this perfect answer!

Comment: Did you just steal my answer? =(

Comment: @kugyousha I didn't, and I cant see the exact time when you posted it, it says 3 hours on both your comment and my answer, it wasn't exactly a very complex answer, so can see how we both got to the same conclusion, however, if your's was first (again, I can't see the exact time) I have no problem with you posting an answer and the OP accepting it as the best answer.

Comment: @ArturoMontaño I'm just teasing, I don't care about the points ;) I appreciate your civility. You're right it was a really simple answer and we did come up with it at almost the same time either way.